# How to perform a power analysis in this case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I want to know how to perform a power analysis in the following case to know if my sample is good enough or not.

In my faculty, we have decided to apply a new lecturing methodology to a set of students, and we hypothesized that if we apply this methodology, then more than half of the students will have a drop in their marks.

However, we were only be able to test this methodology in a group of 30 students, because another classroom of approximately the same number of students was not able to follow this new methodology. We have also applied an h-test in our group, but we have received the critique that the sample size might be too small for such a text.

How to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Now you have the data the concept of power becomes much less relevant as it is more of a planning issue. You can carry out your test and see what happens. It may well be that you cannot detect even quite a scientifically meaningful difference with what you have but that is life. You ask what you should do and I am afraid if the anonymous critic persists your only remedy may be to run the experiment on more classes.